# How To Get Value of Slider Before Slider Manipulation Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to get the value of a slider before the start of the slider manipulation.

Using an on focus event works if the user clicks with the Jquerymobile slider input box.  But it doesn't work if the user manipulates the slider.

A slidestart event doesn't work.  It's always a little off the slider value before the slidestart event??

Is there a way to call the last value of a slider input?  Or capture the slider value before it's manipulated?

Here's what I've tried so far...

(In this example, I want to listen for any changes to sliders in class entry_percent.)

```
var entry_percent_class = $('.entry_percent');
var previous_value;
var change;


$( ".entry_percent" ).on( 'slidestart', function( event ) {
    previous_value = $(this).val();
    alert(previous_value);

});

entry_percent_class.on('tap', function() { // if the user inputs a number in the slider box, capture the number before it's changed.
    previous_value = $(this).val();
    alert(previous_value);

});



entry_percent_class.on('focus', function() { // if the user inputs a number in the slider box, capture the number before it's changed.
    previous_value = $(this).val();
    //alert(previous_value);

});

entry_percent_class.on('change', function() { // if the user inputs a number in the slider box, capture the number before it's changed.
        previous_value = $(this).val();
        //alert(previous_value);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `stop` event to save the value and rescue it whenever you want. Better than using variables, use `data`:

```
$( ".entry_percent" ).on( 'slidestart', function( event ) {
    previous_value = $(this).data("oldvalue");
    alert(previous_value);
});

$( ".entry_percent" ).on( 'slidestop', function( event ) {
    $(this).data("oldvalue",$(this).val());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1gtxaakx/1/)

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me about the data tag.  It works perfectly.